# Append invoice list EDI message on outgoing batch

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2009, edifact

One of our partners requires that a "summary" edi message is appended to any EDI invoice interchange (apparently known as "invoice list"). This message contains a reference that every individual invoice should have in an `RFF` segment, as well as the cummulated `MOA` values.

My question is: does BizTalk Server (in particular BizTalk 2009) provide a convenient way to append another EDI message to the outgoing EDI batch upon release? I cannot find anything on MSDN.

My current idea is to append it in the send pipeline of the port that will transmit the batch, but I really would like a more convenient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll put it this way, your Trading Partner has a rather unusual, perhaps unique, requirement that is itself inconvenient.  So, sorry, there is no 'convenient' way to accomplish this in BizTalk, probably in any platform either.

Anyway, here's what I would do, or at least some things I would try.

- Batch the Invoices normally, such as with the Batching Service.
- Subscribe to the Batch with an Orchestration.
- Map the Batch to the Summary, which ever transaction that is, but it has to be X12/EDIFACT.
- Use a dual input Map to create the batch with the summary appended.
- Send to Send Port with the EDI Assembler.

I'm thinking it would be easier to use a Custom Xslt for the appending Map.  That would save you from having to create a Schema for the Batch message, which doesn't actually ship with BizTalk.

The Xslt itself would be pretty simple since you just copying the two Messages.  FYI, the Batch Message Orchestration Type wold be Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Any.  You can't use XmlDocument as a Map source.

Comment: Great suggestion, we always use custom XSLT so that will not be a problem. What do you mean though with `it has to be X12`? The standard is EDIFACT in this case, does that make a difference?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I saw MOA and assumed X12.  I'm in North America.  The summary just has to be the same standards as the batch, that's all.

Comment: No problem. Before I'll implement this, I'll try to reason with the trading partner about the usefulness of their requirement. I can debunk any claims about added value, for as far as I can see, there is none. Your first paragraph gave me confidence to discuss this, so thank you either way for your answer.

Comment: this is not an unusual request. I don't know about other countries but in germany an invoice list is quite common. It makes payment much easier for regulators.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek how exactly does it make payment easier?

Comment: they pay only a single sum with reference to a list instead of any number of individual invoices. This is mostly interesting for regulators paying large quantities of invoices for their customers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement once, but instead of one specific summary message, I needed to be able to have full control over the the order of the EDI messages in the batch.

This is how I solved this at the time: http://blog.codit.eu/post/2009/11/10/Outbound-EDI-batching-in-BizTalk-Server-2009.aspx

It does have some downsides, but it might be handy to know.